# Личные местоимения "ты" и "вы", как правило, не являются обращениями

Tags: обсценная-лексика

> И вот представление в разгаре, а камерой он так ни разу и не
>   пошевелил. Я через головы людей проползаю и теперь шиплю уже: «Слышь
>   ты, давай снимай, б****!» Он лениво так пару раз в разные стороны
>   повел и опять сел.

Интересует авторскость отсутствия запятой перед "ты" и...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[источник](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...и как традиционно сокращают обсценное слово до "цензурного" уровня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**СЛЫШЬ (ТЫ), СЛЫШЬ, СЛЫШЬ-КА, вводное выражение, *просторечное***
Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.
[**слышь ты**](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=684)

***Слышь ты,*** смолоду, сударь, она
В барском доме была учена
Вместе с барышней разным наукам...
...
На какой-то патрет всё глядит
Да читает какую-то книжку...
Инда страх меня **, слышь ты,** щемит,
Что погубит она и сынишку...
[**Н.Некрасов, В дороге, 1845**](http://www.kostyor.ru/poetry/nekrasov/?n=18)

*...каплю последнюю **, слышь ты,** мальчишка, туз...

Буйному, глупому **, слышь ты,** без абшида с места укажут; ты кто?!*
[**Господин Прохарчин. Белые ночи**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=NPQXGzve5osC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=2QTdzkNN16&sig=aDrMilZsoR7QqGGoKthqbHX0mHo&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFjumuhvXTAhVGYpoKHVL7CTY4MhDoAQhYMAg#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D1%8B&f=false)

*...люби Бога; люби Царя, отечество, люби ближнего, и исполняй божеские и царские законы не криводушно; это **- слышь ты -** первая и главная наука...*
[**Рассказы Старого воина о Суворове**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dwSPBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=2kRv8H9oxL&sig=8itz7INK3Ey2idx94mWSrss_gMc&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZs93ZivXTAhVjKpoKHdbGCW04RhDoAQgqMAI#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D1%8B&f=false)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**"ТЫ" - как обращение:**

*- Слышь, ты, Бриджит Бардо! Она тебя в голом виде в Африку пустит гулять!

 - Слышь, ты, звероящер! - Кто?..- Послышалось...

 - Ну, ты, жертва аборта!*
(крылатые фразы отечественного кино)

*- Слышь, ты, джин, блин.*
[**Хоттабыч**](http://vvord.ru/tekst-filma/Hottabyich/4)

По поводу ***особенного*** слова. Я в одном из своих ответов на Форуме написала так: "б..!".
Когда в тексте полно ругательных слов, вряд ли кто-нибудь подумает, что ***это*** - блоха, блесна или бляшка. Всем всё понятно и с одной буквой.

Comment: Римма, а что другие примеры - с запятой чтобы? И вторая часть вопроса - про сокращение?

Comment: У Вас в ОДНОМ вопросе - всего - сразу - ТАК много!

Comment: И всего-то: «Слышь ты, давай снимай, б****!»

Comment: Я коротенько дополнила свой ответ. P.S. А вопрос-то далеко не  "и всего-то".

Comment: По поводу блохи. Ну у меня же скрины из книг - и всё по-разному!

Comment: Галина,  разрешите мне использовать  ссылку на Ваш "Обратный отсчет"  -  для дополнения к моему давнишнему ответу на Форуме,  как пример. А скрины? Чем автор смелее - тем больше буковок после "Б".

Comment: Что за обратный отсчёт, не мой, наверное, но - берите, не жалко! )))

Answer (score 1):

> > Интересует авторскость отсутствия запятой перед "ты" и...

Перекликается с пушкинским:

*Ты мне не государь, ты вор и самозванец, слышь ты!*